# Windows Forms Error Provider does not display in custom tab control

Tags: tabcontrol, windows-forms-designer, errorprovider

I'm trying to build a Wizard framework in Windows Forms.  I've managed to glean a lot of useful tips from this and other sites which have gotten me very close to success.  However, I'm having a problem with displaying an ErrorProvider on any tab page other than the *first* page of the wizard.

My Wizard control is a UserControl.  It contains a custom tab control that I've derived from TabControl so that I can hide tabs and ignore attempts to navigate between tabs using keypresses, along with the usual collection of Back/Next/Finish/Cancel buttons at the bottom of the control.

I've used reflection to allow me to raise the validation events on a particular TabPage that belongs to the Wizard Control when I hit the Next button.  (I don't *want* to validate the whole TabControl, only the currently active page.)  When I do this, I see in the debugger that my Validating routine for the controls on the current tab page is correctly called and I see that I've called the ErrorProvider that I've attached to the particular control (a TextBox in this case) with a valid error message.  I set Cancel to true for the CancelEventArgs in the validating routine and that's picked up by the code that uses the reflection mechanism so that I see that I've failed and don't change tabs.  And I set the focus successfully to the control that failed validation.

So all that appears to be working just fine.

Unfortunately, I *don't* see the ErrorProvider's cheery blinking icon unless I'm on the first tab page.  For all of the other tab pages, there's no message visible at all.

I'm baffled.  Any thoughts?  I can provide code snippets, if helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in your case the button that moves to the next step of the wizard is placed **outside** (below) the `TabControl`

I noticed that the icon is displayed correctly if I pressed the button without releasing the mouse button. It seems that the button outside the container gets focused event though a validation error has occurred (normally you would not be able to leave the active control).

I worked around this issue by registering an event handler for the buttons `MouseUp` event to "refocus" the `TabControl`:

```
private void cmdOK_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    tabControl1.Focus();
}
```

**Note:** you also need to set your forms `ActiveControl` property the one of the controls that failed validation.